# Craft 3 icons not found in craftcms/cms/src/icons

Tags: yii, svg

Craft 3 version 3.0.4

When logging into the admin panel on Craft3 for some reason I'm getting a Yii2 PHP Warning for missing icons.

Error message:

```
PHP Warning – yii\base\ErrorException
file_get_contents(<pathtocraft>/craft/vendor/craftcms/cms/src/icons/c.svg): failed to open stream: No such file or directory
```

For some reason this icons folder is not being generated when installing craft3 via composer. This is currently happening on craftcms/cms/src/web/Application.php at line 363 where it tries to load the Yii logo.

Answer (score 1):

Gitignore had a line for `Icon?` which was causing the icon folder to not show up in git commit.